# cake php auth login?

Tags: cakephp

i just want pass parameter throw this ; like :

```
$data=array('username'=>'andrew','password'=>'123456');
$this->Auth->login($data);
```

here as `$data`; whats ever i enter it will log in ; i want it check for authorize user and when i enter correct username and password it work well?

how i can manually log in with `auth` component in cake php 2.0  just with calling `$this->Auth->login()` with passing parameters;
any solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You obviously didnt read the documentation thoroughly.
What you do is to "overwrite" the Auth data no matter what.
You can only do that if the user is already logged in and you modify the data via edit form (and want to update the session data).

You may NEVER use it this way for login!
Use $this->request->data and Auth->login() without any arguments as detailed in the docs:

```
$this->request->data = array('User' =>
    array('username'=>'andrew', 'password'=>'123456')
);
```

The component will automatically use the data provided in your request object (just as any posted form).